# CKEditor not Working iPad and Android

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, ckeditor

I have downloaded the latest version of `CKEditor` (standard) and integrated in `DotNet` (MVC). Its works in system browsers but NOT IN `iPad` and `Android` mobiles.

I did a quite search in Google for this fix but no luck and all posts are 3 years ago.

Please reply back with for this FIX.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i tested this on IPAD, it dose not work smoothly. but tapping multiple times or hold and release text area also popup the onscreen keyboard.

Comment: any fix for this to make it work in IPAD?

Comment: on all forums it is bug from apple side. do not know when it will be perfectly fixed. currently user can type by multiple tappings :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code:

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;
</script>
```